# What does "I'd" stand for?

Tags: modal-verbs

> [When Harry blurted out the name ‘Voldemort’ which wizards are afraid of voicing, Ron gasped and said]
>   "You said You-Know-Who's name!" said Ron, sounding both shocked and impressed. "**I'd** have thought you, of all people [...]"
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

What does "I'd" mean? If it is "I would," the part following "of all people" should be "you would be the last to say the name, for you lost your parents because of him."  If it is "I should," the next part should be "you have the courage to say the name, then why do I have to gasp?"

Comment: The "I'd" is not in clause about Harry being the last to say the name; it's in the frame sentence "I'd have thought [that]" = "I would have thought that" = something like "I expected that".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"I'd" can be short for "I would" or "I had". You have to tell which from context.

"I would" makes the most sense here. "I would have thought ..."

Comment: It can also be short for *I had*.

Comment: When is "I'd" used for "I did"? I don't think this is a standard contraction. Do you have a reference? [I do](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/i'd). And also it's never used for "should" in the sense of obligation.

Comment: RE "I did": Maybe not. Now that you mention it, all the examples I can think of could just as well have been intended to be "I would". RE "I should": Probably true. Of course the catch to a contraction is that, by definition, it leaves out information, and while it is usually possible to determine the writer's or speaker's intent, there may be ambiguity.

Comment: *I would* or *I had*, but not *I should* or *I did*.

Answer (score 10):

The contraction **I’d** can mean either ‘**I would**’ or ‘**I had**’.

- **would** is followed by the bare infinitive (infinitive without to)
- **would** can also be followed by the perfect infinitive (have + past
  participle)
- **had** is followed by a past participle.

[image]

Credits : http://speakspeak.com/vocabulary-articles/does-id-mean-i-had-or-i-would